# Nexmo Inbound Concatenation issue for more than 160 characters

Tags: php, vonage

I am not getting any concat or split messages identification in the responses. I am using US Sprint carrier.

I have set the webHooks URL in Nexmo and capture the response from webHooks.

```
$data = null;
$data['msisdn'] = $request['msisdn'] ?? '';
$data['message_id'] = $request['messageId'] ?? '';
$data['to'] = $request['to'] ?? '';
$data['message_timestamp'] = $request['message-timestamp'] ?? '';
$data['keyword'] = $request['keyword'] ?? '';
$data['text'] = $request['text'] ?? '';
$data['status'] = $request['status'] ?? '';

$data['concat'] = $request['concat'] ?? '';
$data['concat_ref'] = $request['concat-ref'] ?? '';
$data['concat_total'] = $request['concat-total'] ?? '';
$data['concat_part'] = $request['concat-part'] ?? '';
```

I dumped webHooks response on a file one by one.

```
Array
(
    [msisdn] => 11172293038
    [message_id] => 0B000000FCE0362B
    [to] => 11172293038
    [message_timestamp] => 2018-08-01 16:01:04
    [keyword] => THE
    [text] => The facility was clean and spacious. The nurses were a little heavy for my taste. The vending machine ate my change so you owe me 75 cents. Overall I thought it
    [status] =>
    [concat] =>
    [concat_ref] =>
    [concat_total] =>
    [concat_part] =>
    [from] => 11326144391
)
Array
(
    [msisdn] => 11172293038
    [message_id] => 0B000000FCE03733
    [to] => 11172293038
    [message_timestamp] => 2018-08-01 16:01:04
    [keyword] => WAS
    [text] => was a very pleasant experience except for CNN on the television. Please play Fox next time.
    [status] =>
    [concat] =>
    [concat_ref] =>
    [concat_total] =>
    [concat_part] =>
    [from] => 11326144391
)
```

My question is how can I concat the two splitted message into single messages? As I am not getting concat, concat_ref, concat_total or any unique identification so, I can know the sequence of text message.

Comment: Concatenated messages are supported when sending to all major US/Canada carriers except for Sprint. Sprint does not support concatenated SMS. In addition, many smaller US/Canada carriers also support concatenated messages.

Comment: I agree about documentation but I need to implement. because many users belongs to Sprint.

Comment: As it is specified in the documentation, that you can't send the message over 160 chars, I would suggest you to add custom pagination thing in your message body, by checking if the length in more than 160 chars. Definately, you would need to do it for **Sprint**.

Comment: But how can I determine the sequence of text so that I can apply the pagination logic to get the full message in order way.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use the Numbers Insight API before sending the SMS to see if the number is on Sprint, and then do serverside logic to split the message on the server before sending, by adding a 1/4, 2/4 at the beginning/end of the SMS. Or impose a 160 characters limit.

Comment: jaise batya tha waise hi kiya h na